# Chinese citizens wanting to get a US pilot license?

Tags: pilots, pilot-certification, china

I am surprised to see Chinese citizens wanting to get US PPL licenses. The pilot shortage in China does not require anyone to show up with a US pilot license to ask for work. What is driving this phenomenon?

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of people train in the US as there are many flight schools and the costs are very reasonable compared to other locations. Often there's a mechanism to get a license in one's home country on the basis of the US license, or just use the hours and take the practical test in their home country to get a license there.

Additionally, having a US license allows you to fly a US registered airplane, it doesn't matter where in the world it is located, so it could be that many of the airplanes they want to fly have US registrations.

Comment: Ok, but having a US license and flying in another country poses other challenges, such as finding a FAA CFI for the mandatory bi-annual review, as well as an FAA AME to renew your FAA medical certificate. I flew my glider for five years in Germany and it was always a challenge (and expensive!) to get the annual inspection done by an IA.

Comment: I was wondering... do pilots flying for Chinese airlines get paid extra if they have US licences?